# Query Group Keys with Count in Different Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to group a set of key values found in different collections. I need the result to be Value and Count from each of the collections. So the DivisionName Chicago could be in both the first collection and second collection.

Another wrench in this is that I can have up to 15 Submitted.SubmittedForms collections. The issue is the output does not combine the values. I will get two separate lines for Chicago for instance. One for each collection with a total count after the two lines.

```
"SubmittedForms" : {
    "SubmittedForms" : {
        "0" : {
            "FullName" : "John Smith",
            "EmailAddress" : "'testmail@att.net",
            "PhoneNumber" : "(555) 555-5555",
            "MarketId" : LUUID("24c111da-bc1c-b14c-8ee9-a4e9d25d4a91"),
            "Comments" : "Please send me more information                                    ",
            "EmailSent" : "1",
            "InternalEmailSent" : "0",
            "SubmittedTime" : ISODate("2017-04-27T15:10:17.507Z"),
            "DivisionName" : "Columbus",
            "CommunityName" : "Test Ridge",
            "ProductType" : "Test"
        },
        "1" : {
            "FullName" : "John Smith",
            "EmailAddress" : "'testmail@att.net",
            "PhoneNumber" : "(555) 555-5555",
            "MarketId" : LUUID("67c503da-bc1c-b14c-8ee9-a4e9d25d4a91"),
            "Comments" : "Please send me more information                                    ",
            "EmailSent" : "1",
            "InternalEmailSent" : "0",
            "SubmittedTime" : ISODate("2017-04-27T15:10:17.507Z"),
            "DivisionName" : "Austin",
            "CommunityName" : "Test Another Ridge",
            "ProductType" : "Test Product"
        },
        "2" : {
            "FullName" : "John Smith",
            "EmailAddress" : "'testmail@att.net",
            "PhoneNumber" : "(555) 555-5555",
            "MarketId" : LUUID("adfadsf-bc1c-b14c-8ee9-a4e9d25d4a91"),
            "Comments" : "Please send me more information                                    ",
            "EmailSent" : "1",
            "InternalEmailSent" : "0",
            "SubmittedTime" : ISODate("2017-04-27T15:10:17.507Z"),
            "DivisionName" : "Austin",
            "CommunityName" : "The Village",
            "ProductType" : "Test"
        },
        "3" : {
            "FullName" : "John Smith",
            "EmailAddress" : "'testmail@att.net",
            "PhoneNumber" : "(555) 555-5555",
            "MarketId" : LUUID("y4444-bc1c-b14c-8ee9-a4e9d25d4a91"),
            "Comments" : "Please send me more information                                    ",
            "EmailSent" : "1",
            "InternalEmailSent" : "0",
            "SubmittedTime" : ISODate("2017-04-27T15:10:17.507Z"),
            "DivisionName" : "Columbus",
            "CommunityName" : "Test Case",
            "ProductType" : "Test"
        }
    }
},
```

This is what I need to see:
Chicago 23
Atlanta 12
New York 14

This is what I tried to do:

```
db.Contacts.group({
"key": {
"SubmittedForms.SubmittedForms.0.DivisionName": {"SubmittedForms.SubmittedForms.0.DivisionName":1,$exists:true,$ne:null,$where: "this.name.length > 0"},
"SubmittedForms.SubmittedForms.1.DivisionName": {"SubmittedForms.SubmittedForms.1.DivisionName":1,$exists:true,$ne:null,$where: "this.name.length > 0"}
},
"initial": {
"countDivision": 0
},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
  if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
    else prev.countDivision++;
},
"cond": {
    _id: {
        "$ne": ["/TESTING.COM/i"]
    },
    "SubmittedForms.SubmittedForms.0.SubmittedTime": {
        "$gte": new ISODate("2017-08-12 07:47:00Z")
    }
}
});
```

[This is the current structure and were the submitted forms live.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFTh.png)

Comment: Rather than posting pictures taken from screenshots it would be better to include the sample "text" of 2 or 3 documents and then also show that the expected aggregation result would be. The picture does not even really add anything since it's really just a picture showing that there are other keys inside what would appear to be named keys. And it would then raise the question of *"why not simply use an array?"* rather than the current nested named keys, that in fact look like more of an implementation error rather than intentional.

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the question with a sample doc. I need to see counts of each divisionname. So it would be something like Chicago 23 Atlanta 12 New York 14. Let me know if that makes better sense.

Comment: Whilst the question is somewhat better for including the sample documents, the real thing you were supposed to take away from that was *"...looks more like an implementation error...*". Which is exactly what it looks like. So the error here is your existing code is nesting the same named key inside itself, as well as serializing entries which "should be in an array" as "named keys" instead. So it would be far more productive to actually fix these errors and store as an array, rather than try to work out how to query the present structure "as is". Fix the data. It will only cause more problems.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn I attached an image of how the submitted forms live in the parent collection. I am somewhat new to MongoDB as as you can tell I am trying to understand what you are saying. Are you saying that currently the data is nested too deep and using the same key is causing an issue? Should it somehow be below the parent collection differently? The path of the keys are different even though they are named the same.

Comment: Just an FYI. This structure may have to remain as is so if there is a solution to query the existing one I would like to get input on that.